# Dynamically Adding Attributes for jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, attributes, collapsable

I'm adding the attribute data-role="collapsible" to 2 forms here: https://www.myhhf.com/test/test_jq_form.php.

Form 1, at the bottom, is correct. This attribute is being added inline.

Form 2 is incorrect. This attribute is being added dynamically with this line of code inside of `$(document).ready(); : $("#form_2").attr("data-role", "collapsible");`. I tried adding `.trigger("create")` to the end, but that did nothing.

Form 2 is receiving the attribute, but it is not working properly.

I do believe that jQuery Mobile applies everything on load. I'm not 100% sure of this. But whether or not this is the case, I need to make this work. I'd be greatful for any help you could provide.

Comment: Pls post code related to your issue not an external link.

Comment: Instead jQuery 1.6.2, use at least jQuery 1.9.x. The data-role="page" should be in a div under the BODY, not the body itself. instead of $(document).ready(function(e) {... Use $(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){..., then just call $("#form_2").collapsible();

Comment: @Omar I showed you all the code that was needed in the explanation.

Comment: @ezanker Why should I use $(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){... instead & why should the data-role="page" attribute be below the body tag? Neither of these things were causing any sort of issue.

Comment: @CrystalMiller, although not absolutely needed, see recommended page setup: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/pages/, pagecreate event is actually when the jQM pages are created but not yet enhanced: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/

Comment: Ah, thank you. I must have missed that in my reading. Thank you for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn it into a `collapsible` by calling `$("#form_2").collapsible();`. There's no need to add the attribute.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything about this in the API, though. Can you tell me where you found this information?